# Ruby - парсинг JSON-строки

Tags: json, ruby

Есть такая строка после парсинга JSON:

```
{
  "status"=>"ok",
  "meta"=>
    {
      "count"=>1
    },
  "data"=>
    {
      "8"=>
        {
          "creator_id"=>32405797,
          "recruiting_options"=>nil,
          "leader_id"=>61286817,
          "description"=>"...",
          "creator_name"=>"...",
          "color"=>"#756D95",
          "clan_id"=>8,
          "created_at"=>1438734986,
          "updated_at"=>1449518817,
          "leader_name"=>"...",
          "members_ids"=>
          [
            2160046, 2172167, 2727455, 4135104, 4667154, 7591288, 7983406, 14092742, 15669731, 19205921, 20141381, 22561097, 28397844, 30358570, 30994384, 31344478, 32405797, 32644252, 33185735, 34644161, 34817735, 35159051, 35176170, 35442556, 35501660, 35593937, 35736155, 36021979, 36409340, 36493500, 36791942, 40210735, 40325047, 40808394, 41435418, 41538404, 41999796, 42422041, 47792722, 48239548, 57203652, 57538797, 61286817
          ],
          "recruiting_policy"=>"restricted", 
          "tag"=>"...", 
          "is_clan_disbanded"=>false,
          "old_name"=>"...", 
          "emblem_set_id"=>10011,
          "members_count"=>43,
          "motto"=>"...", 
          "renamed_at"=>1439995383, 
          "old_tag"=>nil, 
          "name"=>"..."
        }
    }
}
```

Как получить все значения из `members_ids`?

Comment: Это не строка, это хэш. Отформатируйте, пожалуйста его содержимое так, чтобы после каждой запятой был переход новой строке, и я отвечу на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @mix спасибо за форматирование) У меня не хватило терпения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил ваш хэш, запустил Irb. Массив `"members_ids"` лежит тут:

```
<Переменная с хэшем>['data']['8']['members_ids']
```